# Black Box Measure

Tags: capacitor, inductor, circuits

This black box show in the next figure can be created with logic gates, op amps, PIC, FPGA (Basys 2), nevertheless you can’t use any kind of digital - analog converter, the signal obtained on the capacitor is voltage and on the inductor is current. 
[image: Figure of black blox]
Another important thing is that black box have to get a output that is show in the next figure. 
[image]

I don't know how to analyze this graphic because the value of the capacitor and the inductor doesn´t affect the output signal and I have to create the real black box and the output signal have to be equal.

Comment: Define each time interval amplitude with a formula.  Then figure out how to each, e.g. constant slope by dV/dt by Op Amp true integrator, then sequence by 1Hz Johnson counter  and analog switch for example.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist   That formula i have to considerer the value of the inductor or capacitor right?

Comment: you have to consider  Logical Gates, Op amps, PIC, FPGA with caps. These are possible solutions

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist but i dont know the others elements connected with this elements, how i can make a formula without considerer the other elements in the circuit?

Comment: Do you know how to integrate a voltage with an OpAmp to get a straight ramp for 3 seconds?  Or count a binary value and output to a DAC?  Those are 2 examples how to do the first 3 seconds.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Yes sir i know how to do that

Comment: Then do it, then , repeat figuring out how to generate each second(s)

Comment: What course are you taking that assigned this homework? That's probably a clue about how you should look for a solution.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist  And in the case of the inductor, i have not clue to do that

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The course is called circuit II in this course we study op amps, electric energy storage, first orden circuits, second orden circuits and oher main topic

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist But in the case of use a DAC i cant use any analog - Digital converter

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I know how to integrate i signal but i dont know how to limited that ramp in just 3 sec (t)

Comment: sequence each output with an analog switch using Johnson counter with 10 outputs and 5 switches then count 2 sequences and stop. Combine 2 outputs with OR gate or 2 sec. or 3  for 3 s using 3 input OR gate and positive logic. Use DC reg for constant V with RRIO Op Amp or learn how to do it digitally.

Comment: Any more questions?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Yes sir, can i use a multiplexer with integrators (op amps) to generate the signal in t(3)?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist My profesor restrict me use the Johnson counter or any digital circuit is any more analog option?

Comment: Yes, many ways but complicated, this is your homework.  is there another figure after (a)(b) for Figure 4? that says inductor AND capacitor behaviour. Is this for a course related to FPGA's?  Then OK he/she wants you to learn how to do with this Basys 2

Comment: Not such a simple device yet once learned, easy to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your prof wants you to learn Basys 2 so that this problem can be done, perhaps with Johnson counters (lol) and some external 20V amplifier.

### What did I do to guess?

search google for "basys2"  *arbitrary signal generator*

> Then locate  Example 26 – Arbitrary Waveform
>   Using Digilent FPGA Boards

The key to advanced learning is recognizing that everything you must learn is not a new problem. Find the right *buzzwords*, to search for a better solution.  Learn how to learn... faster, smarter.   Practice makes better!

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advises and explanations!!